# Add Inside Labels to horizontal stacked bar chart chart.js using 'chartjs-plugin-labels'

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, stacked-chart

I have the following package installed to add labels to my charts -

```
import * as pluginDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-labels";
```

It is working fine on my line charts, pie charts and normal bar charts. However, it isn't displaying anything on my stacked bar chart. Here is my code:

```
  public stackedChartLabels = ["Test 1"];
  public stackedChartPlugins = [pluginDataLabels];
  public stackedChartData = [
    {
      label: "Low",
      data: [67.8],
      backgroundColor: "#D6E9C6", // green
      stack: "a",
    },
    {
      label: "Moderate",
      data: [20.7],
      backgroundColor: "#FAEBCC", // yellow
      stack: "a",
    },
    {
      label: "High",
      data: [11.4],
      backgroundColor: "#EBCCD1", // red
      stack: "a",
    },
  ];
  public stackedChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      labels: [
        {
          render: function (args) {
            return args.value;
          },
          position: "inside",
          fontColor: "#023d7d",
          fontSize: 12,
        },
      ],
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 12,
            fontColor: "#023d7d",
          },
        },
      ],
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            fontSize: 12,
            fontColor: "#023d7d",
            precision: 0,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

Here is the html code:

```
            <canvas
              baseChart
              [datasets]="stackedChartData"
              [labels]="stackedChartLabels"
              [chartType]="'horizontalBar'"
              [legend]="false"
              [plugins]="stackedChartPlugins"
              [options]="stackedChartOptions"
              height="150"
            >
            </canvas>
```

Does anyone know how i can get the labels to display? I want them to show the value on each segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixed this:

```
animation: {
      duration: 1000,
      onComplete() {
        let chartInstance = this.chart;
        let ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
        ctx.textAlign = "end";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.font = "10px sans-serif";
        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
          var label = dataset.label;
          var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
          meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
            var data = dataset.data[index];
            if (label.indexOf("%") >= 0) data += "%";
            ctx.fillText(data + "%", bar._model.x, bar._model.y);
          });
        });
      },
    },
```